# Implement function call after user taps on screen rhythmically

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

Have a question, would like to implement a function call, wherein the user taps the screen in a rhythm like Morse Code, then we can execute the function.

(building a little easter egg thing)
Would be building this for both IOS and Android

Have absolutely no clue where to even begin. 
For IOS I'd start with a gesture tap recogniser...

If registering the morse code thing is too much work, a preset number of taps before the function is executed would be easier to implement I imagine.  For example the user taps a spot on the screen 15 times or something like that.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Then I can start googling in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutelly no mistery...

you will have an list of touch timestamps and for every time users taps the desired item you add one more

```
    public void onClickListener(){

    rhythm.add(System.currtentTimemillis());
    if(findPattern(rhythm))
    doEasterEgg();

}
```

how you will detect a pattern in the intervals you decide... but morse code shall be way more simple than detect musical rhythm.